# How to set Kafka parameters from a properties file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

What I am doing currently is as below:

```
val topic = "mytopic"
val zkhosts = "localhost"
val zkports = "2181"
```

Setting it in my code and then sending it to kafkastream function works, but I want to read it from `.properties` file. Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 5):

Given this property file at `/tmp/sample.properties`

```
kafka.topic = "mytopic"
kafka.zkhost = "localhost"
kafka.zkports = 2191
```

We could use the plain-old java `Property` API to load the properties:

```
import java.io.FileReader
val configFile = new java.io.File("/tmp/sample.properties")
val reader = new FileReader(configFile)
val props = new Properties()
props.load(reader)
reader.close()
```

You could also use your favorite config library to load the property file as you would on any other program.

For example, you could use the popular [typesafe config lib](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). There're many wrappers for Scala, but in its raw form you could do something like:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val configFile = new java.io.File("/tmp/sample.properties")
val kafkaConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(configFile)

import java.util.Properties
val kafkaProperties = new Properties()
kafkaProperties.put("zookeeper.hosts", kafkaConfig.getString("kafka.zkhost"))
kafkaProperties.put("zookeeper.port", kafkaConfig.getInt("kafka.zkports"):java.lang.Integer)
kafkaProperties.put("kafka.topic", kafkaConfig.getString("kafka.topic"))
```

(There're many ways to make that nice and compact. Here I'm using the most common form)

Comment: @HIRENGALA no problem. Consider accepting the answer to indicate that your question has been answered.